# How to set an option for a serial device?

Tags: bash, serial-port

On a Linux console I want to set the `onclr` option for a serial device. According to the manpage the command is

```
stty [-F DEVICE | --file=DEVICE] [SETTING]...
```

but none of the following commands were able to set the `onclr` flag for the device `/dev/ttyS0`:

```
stty -F /dev/ttyS0 -onclr
stty -F /dev/ttyS0  onclr
stty -F /dev/ttyS0 raw -onclr
stty -F /dev/ttyS0 raw  onclr
```

How to do it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean to type `-onlcr`  you wrote `-onclr`

Comment: Damn, I spelled it wrong! I am really not in best shape today. Thanks for figuring this out...